# Uniform not correctly loading in GLSL but hardcoded value does

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, vertex-shader

I'm trying to multiply vertices by a projection matrix and am testing it with an identity matrix.
When I hard code the identity the resulting image is unchanged as expected

```
#version 330 core 

layout(location = 0) in vec position; 
void main() {
  gl_Position = glm::mat4(1.0f) * vec4(position, 1.0f); 
}
```

However when I load the identity matrix in as a uniform the vertices disappear.

```
glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f); 
GLuint ID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram.ID, "model"); 
glUniformMatrix4fv(ID, 1, GL_FALSE, &model[0][0]);
```

and the shader:

```
#version 330 core 

layout(location = 0) in vec position; 
uniform mat4 model; 

void main() {
  gl_Position = model * vec4(position, 1.0f); 
}
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Most likely you missed to install the program ([`glUseProgram`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUseProgram.xhtml)) before setting the matrix uniform. [`glUniform`*](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml) specifies a value of a uniform variable for the current program object

Comment: ...why are you trying to use GLM types in GLSL?  You got some funky GLSL preprocessing going on?

Answer (score 1):

There are compile errors in both vertex shader.

Error in both vertex shaders:

In *GLSL* The data type `vec` doesn't exist. The name of the data type is `vec3`:

<s>`layout(location = 0) in vec position;`</s>

```c
layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
```

Error in the 1st vertex shader:

`glm::mat4(1.0f)` is C++. In GLSL it is `mat4(1.0)`:

<s>`gl_Position = glm::mat4(1.0f) * vec4(position, 1.0f);`</s>

```c
gl_Position = mat4(1.0) * vec4(position, 1.0);
```